# Allow low level port access for Spring Boot Jar on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, tomcat, spring-boot

Following the instructions [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html), I made an executable jar from my spring boot project (1.5.8) in order to run it as a service (I would like to run it on port `443`). If I just start it with `java -jar proj.jar` I get an error saying the port is in use, but using `sudo java -jar proj.jar` tomcat can start and the site works.

I [tried to allow low level port access to the jar](https://superuser.com/a/892391/196672), but I still get the error. (`sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /path/to/jar` or `setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/jar`)

How can I give the jar/tomcat low level port access, so it runs on 443 and I could launch it as a service?

As a non root user, I installed the jar this way:

1. Cloned the repo
2. `chmod +x ./mvnw`
3. `./mvnw package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`
4. `cd target` and making application.protperties and copying keystore.jks
5. `sudo ln -s /home/user/projectname/target/proj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/projectname`
6. `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/projectname`
7. `sudo update-rc.d projectname defaults`
8. `sudo service projectname start`

Checking the logging file, I can see the error, but as I mentioned, If I start the jar using sudo it works.

`The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope someone can give me a better answer, but I could start the jar If I added low level port access directly to Java (I had oracle installed).:

`sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java`

I guess you could try.:

`sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java`

Should work for OpenJDK too but with different executable locations, I check mine with.: `echo $PATH`