# Spring Boot executable JAR cannot open privileged port as systemd service

Tags: spring-boot

I'd like to run my Spring Boot application as a systemd service listening on port 443 directly (not behind nginx/httpd). To do this, I am specifying `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` in the systemd service unit like so:

```
[Service]
User=myapp
ExecStart=/usr/lib/myapp.jar
SucessExitStatus=143
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
```

However, the capability seems to be lost when the embedded launch script runs Java. As a test, I substituted my own one-line bash script `java -jar /usr/lib/myapp.jar` to see if the capability was lost when running any bash script, but that worked. So as far as I can tell, something in the embedded launch script is causing the problem.

With that said, I'm most likely going to drop the embedded launch script in favor of launching Java directly from the systemd service unit, but in case either (1) others have the same problem or (2) this is an actual bug and not just me missing something I did want to at least ask the question.

Cheers!

Comment: sorry if my guess is stupid but that is what I see: ambient capabilities should be set to the binary being running (I've found it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443/892391#892391)). If I understand correctly the binary in this case is /usr/bin/java or whenever java is installed. So you should try [something like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382820/5185646). but you set it to `myapp.jar`

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, but in the case of the systemd service unit, the capability is passed to the child (and grandchild) processes. Case in point, when I substituted my own bash script that then ran java, it worked.

Comment: please try doing ExecStart=java -jar /usr/lib/myapp.jar (exactly as you did manually). Now you have ExecStart=/usr/lib/myapp.jar, that is something different.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki Sorry for not clearly stating that, of course that works. And as I said, I'm probably going to just use that approach. I was just thrown because the [Spring Boot Documentation for systemd](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-systemd-service) says to use the embedded launch script.